# Cannot read property of 'scrollTo' undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I am trying to add a scroll to function in my app, but it gives me an error on build. `

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ScrollView
} from "react-native";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    
    this.move = this.move(this);
  }

 

  render() {
    return (
       <
      ScrollView style = {
        {
          maxHeight: 200000000,
          height: 1000
        }
      }
      ref = {
        (scrollView) => {
          this.scrollView = scrollView;
        }
      } >
      <
      <
      View style = {
        {
          height: 1000000,
          backgroundColor: "orange"
        }
      }
      /> <
      /ScrollView> 
    );
  }

  move = () => {
    this.scrollView.scrollTo({
      y: 200,
      animated: true
    });
  };
}
```

It gives me an error saying that the property of 'scrollTo' is undefined. I am kind of a beginner to react native and was wondering if i could get any help.

Comment: Where are you setting the value for this.scrollView?

Comment: I figured out the issue, turns out I was calling the scrollTo function before the scrollRef was defined in the constructor. Thanks for trying to help though.